# TKinter not inserting a string to Text widget

Tags: python, text, tkinter, widget, nonetype

I Apologize in advance for the long code and if I break any rules as this is my first time asking a question on this site. I'm fairly new to Python but I'm currently writing a program for a school project that requests data from the OpenFEC API and then display it in a GUI that I created using TKinter. Everything works well if I print to the console but once I try to insert my data to the Text widget I get an error and not all the data is shown. The error is 'TypeError: must be str, not NoneType', I've tried converting the variable to a string using str(varName) but doesn't work. I've been working on this specific issue for a couple of days now and have searched all over the internet for possible solutions but I haven't found anything that helps me. I appreciate any help that I can receive.

```
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def inputValidation(year):
    # Ask the user for a year
    # year = yearEntry.get()
    # Input validation
    year = int(year)  # Converting input to integer for comparison purposes
    if year >= 2003 and year <= 2020:
        message = "Here are the election dates  for " + str(year) + ':' + '\n'
    else:
        message = "Please enter a valid year."
    # Clear out any existing text from entry window
    data.config(state=NORMAL)
    data.delete(0.0, END)
    # Set the data window
    data.insert(1.0, message)
    data.config(state=DISABLED)
    # Convert the year back to a string
    year = str(year)
    return year

# Function to get API data
def apiCall(event, year, pageNumber):
    """ Requests data from OpenFEC API by constructing a url using predetermined
     values. """
    apiKey = 'rdudHBjgS5srIohVWYyyUL64AOsqVfRkGZD4gvMU'
    perPage = '90'  # Number of items to print per page
    electionYear = year
    nullHide = 'true'
    nullOnly = 'true'
    sort = sortNum.get()
    if sort == 1:
        sort = '-election_state'
    if sort == 2:
        sort = '-election_date'
    if sort == 3:
        sort = 'office_sought'
    url = ('https://api.open.fec.gov/v1/election-dates/?per_page=' + perPage +
           '&api_key=' + apiKey +
           '&election_year=' + electionYear +
           '&page=' + pageNumber +
           '&sort_hide_null=' + nullHide +
           '&sort_null_only=' + nullOnly +
           '&sort=' + sort)
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read().decode()
    js = json.loads(data)
    print(url)
    return js                         # We receive a dictionary with all the 
info requested

# Function to print the API info
# Provide a year between 2003 - 2020
def electionDates(event):
    year = yearEntry.get()          # User provided year
    year = inputValidation(year)
    pageNumber = '1'
    js = apiCall(event, year, pageNumber)  # Call the API by using the first function
    pages = js['pagination']['pages']
    print('TOTAL PAGES: ', pages)
    # print('TOTAL ITEMS: ', items)
    while int(pages) >= int(pageNumber):
        idx = 0
        totalItems = 0
        items = 0
        print('PAGE', pageNumber, 'OF', pages)
        for item in js['results']:
            state = js['results'][idx]['election_state']
            date = js['results'][idx]['election_date']
            electionType = js['results'][idx]['election_type_full']
            notes = js['results'][idx]['election_notes']
            office = js['results'][idx]['office_sought']
            # Changing initials from API to full office names
            if office == 'S':
                office = office.replace('S', 'Senate')  # Print out the full word instead of just the initial
            if office == 'H':
                office = office.replace('H', 'House of Representatives')  # Print out the full word, not the initial
            if office == 'P':
                office = office.replace('P', 'President')  # Print out the full word instead of just the initial
            idx = idx + 1  # idx allows us to iterate through each item in the dictionary

            # Displaying Data in Text Box
            data.config(state=NORMAL)
            data.insert(2.0, '' +
                    '\n' 'Date: ' + date +
                    '\n' 'State: ' + state +
                    '\n' 'Election Type: ' + electionType +
                    '\n' 'Office: ' + office +
                    '\n' 'Notes: ' + notes +
                    '\n', END)
            data.config(state=DISABLED)
            items = items + 1
        pageNumber = int(pageNumber) + 1
        pageNumber = str(pageNumber)
        js = apiCall(event, year, pageNumber)  # Re-call the API function to print the next page


# -------- GUI CODE --------
root = Tk()
root.title('InfoLection')
frame = Frame(root)
sortNum = IntVar()

""" Create label, button, entry and text widgets into our frame. """
# --- Create instruction label ---
yearLbl = ttk.Label(root, text='Enter Year: ')
yearLbl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)

# --- Create Entry Box ---
yearEntry = ttk.Entry(root)
yearEntry.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky=W)
yearEntry.delete(0, END)
yearEntry.insert(0, '')

# --- Create Submit Button ---
submitBtn = ttk.Button(root, text='Submit')
submitBtn.bind('<Button-1>', electionDates)
submitBtn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky=NSEW)

# Menu Bar
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
# Submenu
subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='About', menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Information")
subMenu.add_command(label='Exit')

# --- Radio Buttons to Select Sorting Method ---
# Label
sortByRB = ttk.Label(root, text='Sort by:')
sortByRB.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
# Radio Buttons
stateSortRB = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='State', value=1, variable=sortNum)    
# Sort by state
stateSortRB.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
dateSortRB = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='Date', value=2, variable=sortNum)      
# Sort by date
dateSortRB.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
officeSortRB = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='Office', value=3, 
variable=sortNum)  # Sort by Office
officeSortRB.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)

# --- Text Widget To Display Data ---
data = Text(root, width=50, height=25, wrap=WORD)
data.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=NSEW)

# --- Scroll Bar ---
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, command=data.yview)
data['yscrollcommand'] = scroll.set
scroll.grid(row=4, column=5, pady=3, sticky=NSEW)

# Window Icon

# --- Keep Window Open ---
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full Traceback, there are other useful informations

Comment: You're more likely to get help with this if you reduce that code to a [mcve] that focuses on the Text widget problem. The request fetching & JSON stuff is irrelevant. Just make a minimal GUI and supply some fake data (eg in a list of strings) that causes the same error.

Comment: `NoneTye` means you get `None`. Did you found WHY and WHEN you get none in variable?

Comment: Here's the traceback:  `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bryan\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/bryan/Downloads/Alt GUI (1.0).py", line 160, in electionDates
    '\n' 'Notes: ' + notes +
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`

Comment: The code's running for me on Py3 without any errors. Did you edit the code to make the error go away?

Comment: Looks like your *notes* variable has the None... But that doesn't seem to be the code you posted above.

Comment: Check your `notes = js['results'][idx]['election_notes']` line. You must be getting the None from that line.

Comment: The traceback:  `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bryan\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__, return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/bryan/Downloads/Alt GUI (1.0).py", line 160, in electionDates
    '\n' 'Notes: ' + notes +
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`   The Error occurs when I enter a year, for example 2016, in the GUI. I don't know where the None value may be coming from. I know that the "notes" from the API sometimes return 'null' but it doesn't explain why there are errors for some years and not others.

Comment: @Gary02127 I've tried `if notes is None: notes = 'N/A'` and other variations but I still get the same probelm. If I remove 'notes' then the error happens with 'Office', and so on.

Comment: What is a test case? What should be entered to reproduce the problem? What is a working test case, and what is an error test case?

Comment: If you run the code, a GUI will pop up asking for a year between 2003-2020. Then you select a 'sorting' option using one of the 3 radiobuttons. Then, you will see data pertaining to that year but sometimes only a portion of the data parsed from the JSOn file is displayed. Let's say it displays from January to September but it will not show the remaining months, for example, and then throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate `"Notes: "` and `notes`, but sometimes `notes` is None, and you can't add None to a string. You could manually convert:

```
'\n' 'Notes: ' + str(notes) +
```

... But I think it would be easier to take advantage of Python's `str.format()` method, which automatically converts its arguments to strings (in the absence of any specification in the format string telling it otherwise):

```
        data.insert(2.0, ''
                '\n' 'Date: {}'
                '\n' 'State: {}'
                '\n' 'Election Type: {}'
                '\n' 'Office: {}'
                '\n' 'Notes: {}'
                '\n'.format(date, state, electionType, office, notes)
                , END)
```

... Or you could use f-strings, although those are only available in Python 3.6 and higher:

```
        data.insert(2.0, '' +
                '\n' f'Date: {date}'
                '\n' f'State: {state}'
                '\n' f'Election Type: {electionType}'
                '\n' f'Office: {office}'
                '\n' f'Notes: {notes}'
                '\n', END)
```

Comment: The f-strings method worked like a charm. Thank you very much Kevin!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your *notes* variable is coming back as a None.  You can do this to make your code a little more robust and easier to debug:

```
        undefined_s = 'N/A'
        data.insert(2.0, '' +
                '\n' 'Date: ' + (date or undefined_s) +
                '\n' 'State: ' + (state or undefined_s) +
                '\n' 'Election Type: ' + (electionType or undefined_s) +
                '\n' 'Office: ' + (office or undefined_s) +
                '\n' 'Notes: ' + (notes or undefined_s) +
                '\n', END)
```

I found another bug and fixed it.

```
       '&sort=' + str(sort))
       #          ^^^ added the str()
```

and now the code runs.  You should make one of the radiobuttons on by default.

I do see that some of the Notes are coming back as undefined, but this is not a bug, I would say. It's just a matter of what info is on the page you're crawling.  And I do see some of the other fields also coming back as undefined, but, again, that's a function of the pages you're crawling.

Comment: The error went away but so did most of my data. The GUI only displays the 'date'. This is a start though, so I'll keep working from this. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can chain conditional expressions like this. Their precedence is lower than addition's precedence. As a simpler example, consider `"a" if True else "b" + "c" if True else "d"`; you might expect it to return "ac", but it actually returns just "a".

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks, Kevin! That's what I get for being in a hurry! I also found a typo where I put 'is' instead of 'if'. All is fixed in the code now.

Comment: Ok, looking good now :-) Another interesting way of getting behavior like this is to write `(notes or undefined_s)`, taking advantage of `or`'s tendency to evaluate to its leftmost truthy operand.

Comment: I also believe that the issue was with the data but @Kevin's solution fixed the issue!